# Get only twenty five data from hundred data in foreach php

Tags: php, foreach

i am fetching data from xml, where it has 100 elements, my code:

```
foreach($sections->children() as $question){
    $xml_data .= 'Section Name: '.$question->section_name.'<br/>';
    $xml_data .= 'Question No.: '.$question->qno.'<br/>';
    if($question->answer == null || $question->answer == ''){
        $question->answer = 'Not attempted';
        $xml_data .= 'Answer: '.$question->answer.'<br/>';
    } else {
        $xml_data .= 'Answer: '.$question->answer.'<br/>';
    }
    $xml_data .= 'Time: '.$question->time.'<br/>';
    if($question->seen == '1'){
        $xml_data .= 'Seen<br/>';
    } else {
        $xml_data .= 'Not Seen<br/>';
    }
    if($question->flag == '1'){
        $xml_data .= 'Flaged<br/>';
    } else {
        $xml_data .= 'Not Flaged<br/>';
    }
}
```

From above i am getting 100 question but i wabt to display only 25 from above, how should i do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 1;
foreach($sections->children() as $question){

    ...
    ...

    if($count++ == 25){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$t = 1; $rate=array(1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ); print_r($rate); foreach($rate as $rt){ echo $rt; if($rt==3){ exit;} $t++; }
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. `$t<=25` OR `$t=>25`